# Math.floor is counting var without decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this in one longer script:

```
var formatIn = function(momentInMinutes){
    var message = '';
    var days = 0;
    var now = toMinutes(getCurrentHourFormatted());
    var remainingMinutesToday = 24*60-now; 

    if (momentInMinutes > remainingMinutesToday){

            days = Math.floor((momentInMinutes-remainingMinutesToday) / (24*60));

            if (days <= 1){
                message += messages['tomorrow'];
            } else if (days > 1){
                message += messages['in'] + ' ' + (days) + ' ' + messages['days'];
            }

    } else {
            console.log("Nothing." + momentInMinutes);
    }
```

The problem is that days output after Math.floor is 1. But right now when I'm counting:
momentInMinutes console output is 2803 and remainingMinutesToday is 763 so 2803-763=2040/1440=1,416666.... But the console shows 1 as an output of days and then it is always days <= 1 when it's not above 2 even when it should be "else if (days > 1)".

Thank you for all your help.
PS: The last else is there just for debugging now because I can't get it to work.

Comment: "_But the console shows 1 as an output of days_" - Huh? Isn't that exactly what `Math.floor()` is supposed to do? "[_The `Math.floor()` function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)". What did you _expect_ to happen? If you expect `1,416666...`, then just remove the `Math.floor()` around it?

Comment: Math.floor always runds down your decimal results.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's a downloaded plugin, I just found that bug it shows 2 days before with tomorrow info. Now I know where to look. You could post it as the answer because now I at least know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. It's a downloaded plugin, I'm not good at JS but your point about Math.floor guided me to solve it.

A changed it to:

```
    if (days < 1){
        message += messages['tomorrow'];
    } else if (days == 1){
        message += messages['in'] + ' ' + (days) + ' ' + messages['day'];
    } else if (days > 1){
        message += messages['in'] + ' ' + (days) + ' ' + messages['days'];
    }
```